# XSLT for wrapping immediate following-siblings of certain condition

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following source XML

```
<root>
  <i type="r"/>
  <i type="s"/>
  <i type="r"/>
  <i type="r"/>
  <i type="s"/>
  <i type="r"/>
  <i type="s"/>
</root>
```

My goal is to wrap together all  occurrences with all *immediate* following-siblings (1..n) of type="r".

No wrapping for:

- type="r" nodes w/o preceding type="s" node
- type="s" nodes w/o immediate following type="r" node

Expected output:

```
<i type="r"/>
<wrap>
  <i type="s"/>
  <i type="r"/>
  <i type="r"/>
</wrap>
<wrap>
  <i type="s"/>
  <i type="r"/>
</wrap>
<i type="s"/>
```

I have been trying to resolve the problem with the following XSLT snippet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./i">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="current()[./@type='r' and count(preceding-sibling::i[@type='s']) = 0]">
      <!-- Processing w/o wrap -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" mode="fill"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="current()[./@type='s' and following-sibling::i[@type='s']]">
      <!-- Processing w/o wrap -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" mode="fill"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="current()[./@type='r' and count(preceding-sibling::i[@type='s']) > 0]">
      <!-- Do nothing -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="current()[./@type='s' and following-sibling::i[1][@type='r']]">
      <wrap>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current() | //i[@type='r' and preceding-sibling::i[@type='s']" mode="fill"/>
      </wrap>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm constantly failing in defining the right context inside  .

Need to note that subsequent templates are processing all  nodes. These templates have been omitted due to being irrelevant to the problem itself.

Comment: Search for "XSLT positional grouping" and "XSLT sibling recursion" to find similar problems. Note that this problem becomes very easy in XSLT 2.0 (use `xsl:for-each-group/@group-adjacent`), so upgrade if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <i type="r">1</i>
  <i type="s">2</i>
  <i type="r">3</i>
  <i type="r">4</i>
  <i type="s">5</i>
  <i type="r">6</i>
  <i type="s">7</i>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="r" match="i[@type='r']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::i[@type='s'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('r', '')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="i[@type='s']">
            <xsl:variable name="r" select="key('r', generate-id())" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$r">
                    <wrap>
                        <xsl:copy-of select=". | $r"/>
                    </wrap>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <i type="r">1</i>
   <wrap>
      <i type="s">2</i>
      <i type="r">3</i>
      <i type="r">4</i>
   </wrap>
   <wrap>
      <i type="s">5</i>
      <i type="r">6</i>
   </wrap>
   <i type="s">7</i>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two key approach.

```
<xsl:key name="r" match="i[@type = 'r']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::i[@type = 's'][1])"/>
<xsl:key name="s" match="i[@type = 's']" use="generate-id(following-sibling::i[@type = 'r'][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="i[@type = 's']">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Does this s have following r's?-->
    <xsl:when test="key('r', $id)">
      <xsl:element name="wrap">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <!-- Output the r's that immedately follow this s. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('r', $id)">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>  
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i[@type = 'r']">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
  <!-- Only output r if it does not have a preceding s. -->
  <xsl:if test="not(key('s', $id))">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>  
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Create a template to walk through the nodes on the document. -->
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```